# Problem drawing a triangle int with asterisk

Tags: c

I want to ask about a class project which I don't understand why it doesn't work. The objective is to print a spiderweb-like hexagon with the following conditions:

- Each horizontal side has to be printed as "asterisk, space, asterisk" so the asterisk-space as well as the double space print have to be double.
- The spaces remaining out of the hexagon have to be single.

What it should look like:

[image: images of correct output]

The problem is that as equal as the condition for the variables `k` appear, the right sides prints are wrong. Could you help me? Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lado, i=0, j=0, k, l; //k and l represent the spaces but whenever they are coincident with j they should print an asterisk and a space. j is a variable to find coincidences for printing asterisks
    printf("Spiderman, que tamano de telarana deseas:\n");
    scanf("%d",&lado);

    //for the high half
    for( i=1, k=lado,l=(2*lado)-1 ; i<=lado;i++,k--, l++){

        for( j=1;j<(3*lado)-1; j++){

            if((j<k||j>l)){
                printf(" ");
            }else if((i == 1 && j >= k && j <= l )||(i == lado && j >= k && j <= l )) {
                printf("* ");
            }else if((i!=1 && j==k && i!=lado)||(i!=1 && j==l && i!=lado)) {
                printf("* ");
            }else if((j==((2*lado)-i))||((j==(lado-1)+(i-1)))){ //el que rula guay es el 1
                printf("* ");

            }else 
                printf("  ");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    //for creating the low half of the hexagon
    for( int i2=1, k2=2,l2=(3*lado)-3 ; i2<lado;i2++,k2++, l2--){
        for( int j2=1;j2<(3*lado)-1; j2++){

            if(j2<k2 || j2>l2){
                printf(" ");
            }else if(i2 == (lado)-1 && j2 >= k2 && j2 <= l2 ) {
                printf("* ");
            }else if((j2==k2)||(j2==l2)) {
                printf("* ");
            }else if (j2==((2*lado)-1-i2)) {
                printf("* ");
            }else if(j==((lado)+i2)){
                printf("* ");
            }else
                printf("  ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

P.S. "lado" means "side" in Spanish and yeah, the project is about the Avengers lol.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend you describe your approach and where you think it's going wrong. What do all of the single-letter variables represent, for example? What specifically do you need help with? Without these points, it sounds like a "give me the solution" question. See [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much simpler version that allows for both odd and even number of stars on the side.

The basic idea is that the drawing is fully symmetrical in horizontal and vertical direction, so we only have to think about one quadrant. In the following code, `i` goes up by 1 for each line printed, `j` goes up with one for each character printed. The comments should give you an idea about what's happening at each stage.

```
void print_hexagonal_web (int lado)
{
    int i, j, full_i, full_j;
    int size = lado - 1;
    for (full_j = -size; full_j <= size; ++full_j)
    {
        j = full_j >= 0 ? full_j : -full_j; // abs(full_j)
        for (full_i = -2*size; full_i <= 2*size; ++full_i)
        {
            i = full_i >= 0 ? full_i : -full_i; // abs(full_i)
            bool star = false;
            if (j == 0)
                star = i % 2 == 0;
            else if (j == i) // on a diagonal line
                star = true;
            else if (j < i) // below diagonal lines
                star = j <= 2*size-i && (2*size-i-j) % 4 == 0;
            else  // between the diagonal lines
                star = j % 2 == size % 2 && i % 2 == size % 2;
            printf("%c", star ? '*' : ' ');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The output for lado == 8:

```
       * * * * * * * *       
      * *           * *      
     *   * * * * * *   *     
    *   * *       * *   *    
   *   *   * * * *   *   *   
  *   *   * *   * *   *   *  
 *   *   *   * *   *   *   * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 *   *   *   * *   *   *   * 
  *   *   * *   * *   *   *  
   *   *   * * * *   *   *   
    *   * *       * *   *    
     *   * * * * * *   *     
      * *           * *      
       * * * * * * * *
```

The output for lado == 9:

```
        * * * * * * * * *        
       * *             * *       
      *   * * * * * * *   *      
     *   * *         * *   *     
    *   *   * * * * *   *   *    
   *   *   * *     * *   *   *   
  *   *   *   * * *   *   *   *  
 *   *   *   * * * *   *   *   * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 *   *   *   * * * *   *   *   * 
  *   *   *   * * *   *   *   *  
   *   *   * *     * *   *   *   
    *   *   * * * * *   *   *    
     *   * *         * *   *     
      *   * * * * * * *   *      
       * *             * *       
        * * * * * * * * *
```

Updates: typo for abs(full_j) and abs(full_i), missing bracket, declaration of local variables, range of full_i should be from -2*size to 2*size

Comment: Looking sooo nice man. But the problem is that in my class we havent learned about voids or bool yet so it would be strange to appear with this haha. But it is great anyways

Comment: You can remove the void function, and just copy paste everything in the main function. Instead of the bool, you can write every `star = blabla` as `if (blabla) printf ('*'); else printf(' ');`. But please try to do your own homework as much as possible yourself ...

Comment: Instead of `bool`, you can just use `int`. `false`is a nice name for `0`, `true` for `1` .

Comment: Double check your code. `printf("%c", star ? '*' : ' ';` won't compile. You can `putchar()` a single character rather than calling `printf()` and as written your code only prints the center of the diagram. The left and right sides are omitted.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for checking. I first wrote it in Python and then translated to C. Now it should be ok. I didn't want to use putchar because the poster might not be familiar with it.

Comment: That got it. That is a good web solution. Only other thing I would do is use `putchar` to output single-characters, e.g. `putchar (star ? '*' : ' ');` rather than calling the variadic `printf` (even though a good compiler should optimize to the same code regardless). Thanks for updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were missing the intermediate spaces between the webs, try it this way and tell me of anything is not clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int lado, i, j, k, l;
    printf("Spiderman, que tamano de telarana deseas:\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &lado);
    //for the upper half
    for (i = 1, k = lado, l = 2 * lado - 1; i <= lado - 1; i++, k--, l--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 2 * lado - 1; j++) {
            if (j < k)
                printf(" ");
            else if (j > lado && j <= l - 1)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 1)
                    printf("* ");
                else
                    printf("  ");
            }
            else if (j <= lado && (j - k) % 2 == 0 || j > lado && j % 2 == 1)
                printf("* ");
            else if (i % 2 == 0 && (j == lado || j == l))
                printf("* ");
            else
                printf("  ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //for the middle line half
    for (i = 0; i < 2 * lado - 1; i++)
        printf("* ");
    printf("\n");
    //for the lower half
    for (i = lado - 1, k = 2, l = lado + 1; i >= 1; i--, k++, l++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= 2 * lado - 1; j++) {
            if (j < k)
                printf(" ");
            else if (j > lado && j <= l - 1)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 1)
                    printf("* ");
                else
                    printf("  ");
            }
            else if (j <= lado && (j - k) % 2 == 0 || j > lado&& j % 2 == 1)
                printf("* ");
            else if (i % 2 == 0 && (j == lado || j == l))
                printf("* ");
            else
                printf("  ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks great but the only problem is that the side printed is the double of the imput one. If you could tell me how to fix that it would be great but thank you so much anyways

Comment: What do you mean by double? You mean this is for input 8?

Comment: Actually this would be for imput 9, based on the number of asterisks yep

Comment: so should i  create another lado variable?

Comment: I understand now what do you mean by lado, check it now.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what i wanted